# CDC From SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to know is there any way to use SSIS CDC(tools from SQL Server), to Replicate data from SQL Server database to Oracle Database.

Because when I'm searching the documentation.
The tutorial I've only found is:

1. From SQL Server to SQL server
2. From Oracle to SQL Server.

Is there any way to SSIS CDC from SQL Server to Oracle?
And can you give me the link or tutorial?

Comment: Would you mind describing the problem you are trying to solve, please? The docs also contain [this article - 7 minutes read](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/the-oracle-cdc-service?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I want to replicate data from SQL Server to Oracle in real time, and the solution/tools that we want to use is SQL Server CDC, But as we searching tutorial. We didnt find tutorial to  CDC from SQL Server to Oracle. So we need to know is it posibble to use SSIS Sql server to replicate from SQL Server to Oracle?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida I think the article you give didn't answer my question? Because Onthe article ,Oracle is use as Source Database, But i want to use it as a target database? CMIWW

Comment: Yes, I know! I tried to find something about CDC SQL Server to Oracle, but only came across [Oracle Golden Gate](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/datawarehouse-sqlserver-goldengate.html) which is not related to your problem. All I know is that you can connect to Oracle using SSIS, so if you detect changes in SQL Server using CDC and somehow save those changes to Oracle using Oracle Connection Manager in SSIS, I'd say it's possible, but I'd wait on better answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is two options you can use:

1. Use SSIS CDC as in your question. Target for CDC update can by any OLEDB database, there is no requirement that it is SQL Server.
2. (This option is depreciated, so you are safer with CDC) You can use transactional replication and configure Oracle as a subscriber. You can find documentation for this solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/oracle-subscribers?view=sql-server-ver15